# assembly masm can not figure out how to do a if not less then statement

Tags: windows, vb.net, assembly, if-statement, masm

how in assembly masm do you do a if not less then statement

I have this code in vb.net

```
 If Not variable1 < variable2 Then
                count += 1
            End If

If Not variable1 < variable3 Then
                count += 1
            End If

msgbox.show(count)
```

for this code count = 1

I tried all the below code and it does not work. it either gives me count = 2 at the end or count = 0 at the end. it should give me count = 1

here is the code for assembly masm

```
.data

variable1        dd ?
variable2       dd ?
variable3       dd ?
```

this is what is suppose to happen. I read from a text file 3 values they are 500,109,500
they get stored into the 3 variables so

```
variable1 = 500
variable2 = 109
variable3 = 506
```

then I need to list these in order from least to greatest so I tried to compare these.

I tried all of these variations and none of them worked

```
    mov esi, offset variable1
    mov ecx, offset variable2

    .if esi > ecx
    inc count
    .endif

 mov ecx, offset variable3

.if esi > ecx
    inc count
    .endif
```

---

```
    .if variable1 > offset variable2
        inc count
        .endif

.if variable1 > offset variable3
        inc count
        .endif
```

---

```
 mov esi, offset variable1
        mov ecx, offset variable2

    cmp esi,ecx
    JB n2
    inc count
    n2:

mov ecx, offset variable3

    cmp esi,ecx
    JB n3
    inc count
    n3:
```

---

```
    mov esi, offset variable1
        mov ecx, offset variable2

    cmp esi,ecx
    JG n3
    inc count
    n3:

mov ecx, offset variable3

    cmp esi,ecx
    JG n4
    inc count
    n4:
```

---

```
mov esi, [variable1]
mov ecx, [variable2]
cmp esi, ecx
ja n1
inc Level3DNS1rank
n1:

mov ecx, [variable3]
cmp esi, ecx
ja n2
inc Level3DNS1rank
n2:
```

how can i convert the above vb.net code into masm assembly

thank you

**Update**

here is the answer to these 2 questions

what I needed to do was convert the string to an integer. I used this code to do that `invoke atodw,ADDR variable1` for the if not in assembly I just changed                  `if not variable1 < variable2` to `if variable1 > variable2`

Comment: As far as I know, `not <` is the same as `>=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
mov esi, [variable1]
mov ecx, [variable2]
cmp esi, ecx
jge n2
```

### Update

Aha. I see the problem now. You have:

```
variable1        db "500",0
variable2       db "109",0
variable3       db "506",0
```

That gets stored in memory as (the hex bytes):

```
variable1  35 30 30 00
variable2  31 30 39 00
variable3  35 30 36 00
```

But when you load a register from memory, it loads it little-endian. So when you have:

```
mov esi, [variable1]
mov ecx, [variable2]
```

The contents of `esi` is `00303035`, and `ecx` is `00393031`. And the last value is loaded as `00363035`.

You're trying to load a string of characters as an unsigned 32-bit value. Are you really wanting to compare strings?

Comment: i tried that and it still did not work so I added it to the list above of tried and did not work. also I added more info to my post. the code you gave me does work if I am only checking it once but when I check 2 or more back to back if statements it always either inc count all the time or non of the time.

Comment: well here is what I want to do. I have 3 numbers that are read in from a text file and stored in variable1 variable2 variable3. I then need to compare these numbers to rank them in order from least to greatest so my variable1 variable2 variable3 are dd ? then they get the  number from the text file then I need to list them from least to greatest how do i do that

Comment: @patchariadog: So what you really need is some code that will convert a number represented as text (i.e. "509") into a 32-bit integer. Search for that on Google. Lots of examples last time I checked.

Comment: thank you. that is what I needed to do was to convert the string to a integer. I used this code invoke atodw,ADDRSprintDNS1connectionspeed

.if esi > eax
inc NTTAmericaTechnicalOperationsDNS2rank
.endif

Comment: ignore that post I just posted here is the info. thank you that is what I needed to do was convert the string to an integer. I used this code to do that invoke atodw,ADDR variable1  for the if not in assembly I just changed  if not variable1 < variable2  to          if variable1 > variable2